# Qlikview Count of ids in last 12 months in text object (box)

Tags: count, qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

I have two fields in my table `Date` & `ID`, i want to put in a text box the count of all the ids for the last 12 months.

This returns nothing:

```
=Num(count({$<DATE={'>=$(=AddMonths(Today(),-12))'}>}[ID]),'#,##0')
```

This returns the correct count:

```
=count(ID)
```

This returns the total for the year (2015):

```
SUM(IF( year(DATE) = year(today()),1,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `MonthName` function on the date to parse it exactly as the `AddMonths` function does

```
=SUM(IF( (date(Monthname(DATE),'MMM-YY')) >=(AddMonths(Today(),-12)),1,0))
```